# Modificar un error en registro de PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

¿Que tal?

Estoy haciendo un registro haciendo uso de PHP, el registro funciona de forma correcta.

Lo que yo intento hacer ahora, haciendo uso de javascript, que si una persona introduce una letra donde se le pide el numero de telefono, salga el problema mas "detallado"

¿A que me refiero con más detallado?

en PHP lo que sale haciendo uso de:

```
$connect->error;
```

es: **Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'**

entonces pense en plantear este problema en Javascript.

Lo que tengo hecho hasta el momento es:

```
var usuario = document.getElementById("input-nombre");
var email = document.getElementById("input-email");
var celular = document.getElementById("input-celular");
var pass = document.getElementById("input-pass");

function registro(){
    if (celular === 'a' ){
        var msgERRNO = "Error";

        alert(msgERRNO);
    }
}



registro();
```

Esto no estaria funcionando, y no sabria porque.

¿Alguien sabe como hacer que esto funcione?

Gracias!
Saludos

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es restringir el tipo de caracteres que el usuario puede introducir? Otra cosa que no me queda claro es que si `celular` es el valor que introduces a la tabla, el error es un error de columna y no de tipo de dato. También ayudaría si mostraras el código de insert y que plantearas un poco mejor el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener una función que retorne falso en caso de que el usuario inserte cualquier letra en el input:

---

```
<input id="celular" name ="celular" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)" />
```

```js
function justNumber(e) {
   var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
   if ((keynum == 8) || (keynum == 46))
      return true;

   return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
}
```